# Bolzano-Weierstrass: Positive semidefnite matrix sequences

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Is there a theorem similar to Bolzano-Weierstrass about the convergence of positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix sequences? In other words, is it true that every bounded sequence of PSD matrices has a convergent subsequence? How would you check for boundedness in that case?

Comment: I would imagine the normal Bolzano-Weieirstrauss works for positive semidefinite matrices as well, if only because matrices in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ can be thought of as identified with $\mathbb R ^{n^2}$ equipped with the regular topology? 

Then since all the hypotheses hold you can apply it as normal.

Comment: @imu96 Thanks. How would you check for boundedness for semidefinite matrices if you were to use Bolzano-Weierstrauss? Would you use elementwise boundedness, ie., A<= B if each element of A is less than that of B?

Comment: @Teodorism A sequence of matrices is bounded if there is one big constant $M$ such that all the elements of all the matrices are bounded in absolute value by $M$.

Comment: Weierstrass not Weieirstrauss !

Comment: @Teodorism so you can actually define an inner product $\langle A, B \rangle$ as the trace of $AB^T$ where $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$.  Note that the norm induced by this inner product coincides with the Euclidean norm when the matrix is considered an element of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: @Teodorism Please don't replace your old question with an entirely different one. Doing so will invalidate existing answers.

Comment: It was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a normed vector space then we have:

$ \dim X < \infty \iff X$ has the Bolzano- Weierstraß- property.

$X$ has the Bolzano- Weierstraß- property, if every bounded sequence in $X$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Now let $X= \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be equipped with any norm. Convergence in this norm is element wise convergence.

Can you take it from here ?